# How to make Redirect.INHERIT and System.setOut work together

Tags: java, processbuilder, system.out

This may be a trivial question but I can't easily find an answer. I've got a simple program in Java:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("stdout.txt")));
...
...
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("... some args ...");
pb.inheritIO();
pb.start().waitFor();
```

My intention is to store all output of the process (including child `pb`) in the `stdout.txt`. But, this seem not to work and the output of `pb` is redirected to my process parent's standard output as if `System.setOut(...)` was never called.

Is there any way I can use `pb.inheritIO/pb.inheritOutput` methods to redirect to a *redirected* `System.out`? Am I missing something obvious? I know I can do it *the old way* by reading from the child's standard output manually in a thread but that's just more hassle.

Cheers,
Jacek

Comment: Wonder if anyone has some comments/answers to that?

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, not really. I had to move back to threads that dump the streams in the background.

Comment: I had to do the same. No magic bullet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342557/5226711:

> The I/O redirection of `ProcessBuilder` does not redirect streams but
>   file descriptors. Even setting `System.out` to another stream does not
>   change the file descriptor of the initial standard output.
>   `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()` inherits the parent process' standard
>   output/input/error file descriptors.
>
> The `PrintStream` instance is not passed to the started operating
>   system process, but rather something like (it is pseudo code, I do not
>   think it actually works):
>
> ```
> ((FileOutputStream) System.out.out).getFD()
> ```
>
> Or, more correct:
>
> ```
> FileDescriptor.out
> ```
>
> which is `static final` indicating that it will not change, even if
>   you set `System.out` to something different.

Regarding your question, this means you have to use a `File` and `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(File)` instead of a `PrintStream`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("... some args ...");
pb.redirectOutput(new File("stdout.txt"));
pb.start().waitFor();
```

This redirects only the output of the child process to stdout.txt.

If you want to direct all output from both the parent and the child process, you have to redirect the parent's System.out to the file and capture the child's output in the parent and output it to its redirected System.out:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("stdout.txt")));
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("... some args ...");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader childOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // child`s output goes to stdout.txt
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lars for taking time your answer clarifies things that there's no hope ;-) but capturing child's output manually. Cheers