# ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() sending output to the wrong place

Tags: java, redirect, java-7, processbuilder, system.out

I am using `inheritIO()` to redirect output from a child process in my program to the `System.out` and `System.err`, and input to `System.in`.

These are all redirected by `System.setOut()` and the like:

```
// Reassign System IO
System.setIn(cpanel.getConsole().getInputStream());
System.setOut(new PrintStream(cpanel.getConsole().getOutputStream()));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(cpanel.getConsole().getOutputStream()));
```

However when I run the process:

```
String[] fullargs = new String[sargs.length+4];
fullargs[0] = "java";
fullargs[1] = "-classpath";   // Runtime classpath option.
fullargs[2] = cpath;          // Specify the classpath.
fullargs[3] = mname;          // Specify class to run.

for(int i=0; i<sargs.length; i++)
{
    fullargs[i+4] = sargs[i]; // Put together arguments.
}

ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder()
                            .inheritIO()
                            .command(fullargs);


try
{
    System.out.println("RUNNING...");
    proc.start();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "There was a system error invoking this program.",
        "ERROR",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

It redirects to what **used to be** `System.out` etc. rather than what they've been redirected to.

If I comment out the `inheritIO()` line, the output is lost to time and doesn't appear anywhere. With `inheritIO()` it goes to the standard console of the parent process rather than the redirected one. The line where I print "RUNNING" goes to the proper redirected location. In other words, `inheritIO()` is doing exactly what it should *if I hadn't redirected the output streams of the parent process*. It's going to the parent process's old console.

I have no idea why this is happening and I'm pulling my hair out here. I've seen that `inheritIO()` doesn't work in Windows, but this issue is the same on Mac OS and Linux. I'm using Java 7.

Comment: Does this question could give you a clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki

Comment: @fluminis The solutions in there are for Java 6 and previous. The `inheritIO()` function in Java 7 and above is designed to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350856/5226711

Applied to your question, this means you can use an adapted verion of the StreamGobbler proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165567/5226711:

```
private class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    private InputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;

    private StreamGobbler(InputStream in, PrintStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String[] fullargs = new String[sargs.length+4];
fullargs[0] = "java";
fullargs[1] = "-classpath";   // Runtime classpath option.
fullargs[2] = cpath;          // Specify the classpath.
fullargs[3] = mname;          // Specify class to run.

for(int i=0; i<sargs.length; i++)
{
    fullargs[i+4] = sargs[i]; // Put together arguments.
}

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(fullargs);

try
{
    System.out.println("RUNNING...");
    Process p = pb.start();
    StreamGobbler pOut = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), new PrintStream(cpanel.getConsole().getOutputStream()));
    StreamGobbler pErr = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), new PrintStream(cpanel.getConsole().getOutputStream()));
    pOut.start();
    pErr.start();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "There was a system error invoking this program.",
        "ERROR",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Redirecting stdin of the child is not included in my example.